# Is this a proper way to insert a node after the first for a doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, list

```
NodePtr p = new Node(id, age, email)
p->prev = top;
p->next = top->next;
top->next = p;
top->next->prev = p;
```

I am trying to insert node p after the first node.

I am trying to teach myself how to use doubly linked lists. When I draw it out, it looks like it would work. I just wanted confirmation if this is correct. If this is not correct, how should I fix it?

Comment: Small hint: consider what `top->next->prev` is when you assign it, keeping in mind that in the line above you've made `top->next` equal to `p`.

Comment: Can `top->next` ever be `NULL`, and if yes, then what will `top->next->prev = p;` do?

Comment: Depending on what sort of checks you do before reaching this code, you may needs additional code to handle lists that have 0 or 1 items.

Comment: Impossible to say - it depends what Node, NodePtr, top, prev, next etc. are, which you haven't showed us.

Comment: Theres a pretty simple solution, if you want to know whether your code works: test it.

Comment: @Paul you're a jackass

Comment: @RyanRiis thank you for your kind words. Nevertheless "I just wanted confirmation if this is correct" is solvable by simply writing a test-driver and watch your code crash, misbehave or work out the way it's supposed to. If you want your code tested, you're expected to test it on your own. SO is not an automated testing-tool, but the last resort when you can't resolve a problem on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation doesn't work.

```
top->next = p; // top->next is now p
top->next->prev = p; // p->prev is now p, oops
```

Swap those two lines, and it'll be correct.

```
top->next->prev = p; // top->next->prev is now p
top->next = p; // top->next is now p
```